# zombies resetting model data

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

Running into zombies in my backbone view

this is code snippet

```
initialize: function() {
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
    this.model = ..
    this.model.UID = this.options.UID;
},

doLaunchUI:function(){
    //console.log this.model.UID
    launch jquery ui dialog here with accept and cancel button

    //accept button clicked
    updateUser
},

updateUser: function(){
    //console.log this.model.UID
}
```

start app

```
1st log: uid = 12345
2ndlog: uid = 12345
```

navigate away and back to this page

```
`this.model.UID = this.options.UID;` shows the 2dn user id

1st log = 234566
2md log = 12345
```

the 2nd log always shows the uid of the first user i viewed.

Not sure how and where this is getting reset to the uid of the first user viewed

navigation occurs through tree view

UPDATE:
looking through developer tool in chrome, i noticed in my jquery ui pop up when active, this.model.UID was always set to the 1st user viewed. In my pop up I do not have any view but just static html text [for conducting my test]

Comment: Normally you call `view.remove()` before putting up a new view, calling `remove` in `initialize` is a bit weird. Are there hidden references to your view inside the jQuery UI dialog? Are you properly clean up the dialog?

Comment: I agree wit you but then i would have to redo the whole app which was done by someone else. The ui dialog is calling a html page which for now has only `hello world` in it.

Comment: rendering view with `setView("#content", new View()).render();`

Comment: What is `setView`? Supplying a minimal self contained demo would probably get you answers faster.